# Ошибка при работе с многомерным кортежем. Python

Tags: python

Никак не мог разобраться, что я делаю не так.
Есть кортеж следующего содержания

```
[('28467', '19740', '0'), ('28471', '19740', '0'), ('28472', '20560', '0'), ('28471', '19740', '0'), ('28468', '20560', '0'), ('15872', '20210', '0'), ('12350', '20300', '0'), ('28463', '20210', '1'), ('28467', '19740', '0'), ('28461', '19180', '1'), ('28462', '22300', '0'), ('28461', '19180', '1'),.....
```

Допустим мне нужно поменять первый элемент "28467"

```py
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3=list(bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3)
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3[1][0] = 777
```

Такая запись выдаёт ошибку:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Вы не так учебник читали (о кортежах):-) И не читаете ошибку. Вам же прямо пишут: "Объект кортеж не поддерживает присваивание".  В чём у вас сложность с анализом этой ошибки? (я серьёзно, вам это важно понять, иначе и дальше будут такие проблемы).

Comment: Кортеж - не изменяемый тип. Либо сделать список списков, и тогда вы сможете поменять элемент, либо нужно делать новый список кортежей из старого, с подменой нужного элемента.

Comment: А с чего он вдруг кортеж, если я его преобразовал в список? Или я где то очень сильно туплю.

Comment: Да, вы тупите. Напечатайте список и вы увидите, что внутри него по-прежнему кортежи. Можно преобразовать их так: `bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3 = list(map(list, bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3))`

Comment: Пардон, я не тот код скопировал
Должно быть вот так:
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3=list(bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3)
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3[1][0] = 777

Comment: Да без разницы. Так вы преобразуете в список только внешнюю коллекцию, которая у вас и так уже список. А то, что у неё (у коллекции, то есть списка) внутри остаётся тем же чем и было, то есть кортежами.

Comment: Вот этот момент я упустил, даже не знал, что такое бывает. Спасибо огромное. Я с PHP перехожу на Python,а в PHP таких сложностей нет, там полная анархия.

Comment: Не думаю, что это имеет отношение к конкретному языку, кортежи обычно везде не изменяемые, в любом языке. Скорее всего вы просто не работали до этого с кортежами.

Comment: В PHP просто массив, что хочешь  с ним, то и делай, без ограничений.

Answer (score 1):

Кортеж - не изменяемый тип. Нужно либо сделать список списков, и тогда вы сможете поменять элемент, либо нужно делать новый список кортежей из старого, с подменой нужного элемента.

Почему не работает ваш способ - вы преобразуете в список только внешнюю коллекцию, которая у вас и так уже список. А то, что у неё (у коллекции, то есть списка) внутри, остаётся тем же чем и было, то есть кортежами. Нужно преобразовать в список все элементы, которые находятся внутри списка. Например, с помощью `map`:

```py
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3 = list(map(list, bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3))
```

Либо через *списковое сокращение*:

```py
bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3 = [list(x) for x in bd_final_id0_price1_nal2_uid3]
```